# Where to set Ruby and gems path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on a shared host and need to use my own version of Ruby and keep the gems installed in my home directory as well.

In my Rails 2 app I had this in `environment.rb` to use my own gems:

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  ENV['HOME'] = "/home/matt"
  ENV['GEM_HOME'] = "/home/matt/.gems"
  ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "/home/matt/.gems"
end
```

Is it a good idea to do the same in Rails 3? Or is there any better way?

Is it possible to configure the application to use my local version of Ruby when it's running on Apache/Passenger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting these setting at the top of `config.ru` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use RVM and Bundler on your shared host, you'll be saved (really) :).

Comment: I'm using bundler (I guess it's the only way with Rails 3). But how does that help me to point Rails to correct gems directory? It needs to know where the bundler gem is, for starters.